# How to use own User table to log in to Blazor App

Tags: blazor, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I have an application that was originally created with MVC, DB is already populated with a User table (own table) and other tables (all test data). The user table already has relationships with other tables in the DB.

I am starting a new Blazor app (I am new with it). I will use this app to add some additional features to the original MVC application and people will need to log in using the same credentials. I created it using the built-in authentication (Individual Accounts) which comes with all the basics to log in, register accounts, etc. Great.

But now I want to make it work with my own User table and here is where I don't know how to proceed. Here are a few details:

- People need to authenticate with email and password
- This is a SaaS application so users can log in only if they are part of an Organization. (my User table has an ORG_ID).
- The org ID will be defined by the current subdomain that was used to access the application (I haven't gotten to make this work yet but that is the goal)
- By looking at the migration scripts I noticed it wants me to create a new database with AspNetUser and columns already defined. My User table doesn't have the exact same columns and password is encrypted using an already defined encryption policy.

Is it possible to use the built in authentication to achieve this? or is it better to create it from scratch?

Any recommendations are welcome!

I am just starting this application so I haven't tried anything specific yet. I am just trying to understand what are my options and what is the best solution.

Comment: Side note: Passwords should be Hashed, not Encrypted.

Comment: The Identity services interface with the database through a set of abstract interfaces.  You need to provide custom implementations of these to interface with your database.  The principle  interface is `IUserStore`.  The MSDocs link is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-7.0.  I've looked around and there are some (not very comprehensive) articles on how to implement the interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use the built in authentication to achieve this? or
> is it better to create it from scratch?

It's better not to use built in authentication to achieve your goal. I implemented a Blazor Server app based on Cookie Authentication [here](https://github.com/Kamalifar/BlazorServerCookieAuthentication-master). I hope that it help you.

> People need to authenticate with email and password

You can change the [user](https://github.com/Kamalifar/BlazorServerCookieAuthentication-master/blob/main/Data/User.cs) according to your desired field, for example you can add the Email and ORG_ID field to it.

> password is encrypted using an already defined encryption policy

You can put your defined encryption policy on the [SecurityService.cs](https://github.com/Kamalifar/BlazorServerCookieAuthentication-master/blob/main/Services/SecurityService.cs)

Comment: I'll download your project and get back to you soon, thanks for sharing